# Use (LAlt) instead of (numlock) to play this script

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

```lua
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    end
 if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1) then
        Sleep(5)
        repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
        MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
        Sleep(10)
        Sleep(50)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Replace `IsKeyLockOn("capslock")` with `IsModifierPressed("LAlt")`.  Now you should keep `LAlt` pressed while pressing `LMB` to start the script.  You can not make `LAlt` a toggle key as it was with `CapsLock`.

Comment: what if i want to use (number 9) instead if the numlock ? how can i doit? also i just need to press it 1 time no need to hold, if its not possible to do that with numbers can we doit with letters? for example using (I) instead of numlock to start the bot

Comment: Only the following keys could be a toggle-key: mouse buttons, Logitech keyboard G-keys, lock keys with LED (scrolllock, numlock, capslock).

Comment: np ill remap the keyboard from the regedit to put my numlock in my mouse, ty anyway